# Spring+Vue.js application with Keycloak SSO authentication: XSS jam?

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, xss, keycloak

Since I migrated a Vue.js Spring (Boot 2.1.10) application (localhost:8080) from basic authentication to SSO with Keycloak (6.0.1 over localhost:8180), I'm ending up with XSS-related errors :

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/SpringBootRealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=scorpio&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fsso%2Flogin&state=b89ab247-5b3b-4147-9772-c948a0193044&login=true&scope=openid' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/SpringBootRealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=scorpio&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fsso%2Flogin&state=53308c65-d3f3-4ce7-8710-cffad789f1fc&login=true&scope=openid' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/SpringBootRealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=scorpio&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fsso%2Flogin&state=bfe0aa54-2997-429c-8f14-4ce4b704a7f5&login=true&scope=openid' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. 
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/SpringBootRealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=scorpio&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fsso%2Flogin&state=223d0102-2560-4064-b82b-380972f82a96&login=true&scope=openid' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

I guess that this is related to "X-Content-Type-Options" and/or "X-Frame-Options"; so I tried that configuration:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
public class KeycloakAuthConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to(InfoEndpoint.class)).permitAll()
        .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to(HealthEndpoint.class)).permitAll()
        .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).hasRole(HAB_ADMIN)
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
    http.csrf().disable(); // useless for REST APIs anyway
    http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin(); // this was already necessary with basic authentication
    http.headers().contentTypeOptions().disable(); // added this, but it didn't seem to have an impact
}
...
}
```

I also tried to change Keycloak's realm Security Defenses parameter "X-Frame-Options" value from "SAMEORIGIN" to "ALLOW-FROM localhost"; without success anyways. I thought I'd only have to deal with it at production time, by the way, when application clients would address the SSO from remote machines.

FYI: Valid Redirect URIs set to "http://localhost:8080/*"

Well, I don't think I understand it all regarding that matters, and if anyone has ideas or experience here I'd be glad to learn. Thanks in advance!

Comment: also tried value "ALLOW-FROM http://localhost:8080/ http://localhost:8180/" and "web origins *" in my client's configuration

Comment: also tried "keycloak.cors = true" in the spring boot app; no luck. it isn't clear if the issue comes from the webapp or protocols within Keycloak... I have another app (more simple, thymeleaf) which is fine so far